# unable to set value for a form control in an angular component using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

i am having an angular 5 ui project. I have a text area in my component template html. I am trying to set a value to the text area from the component.ts file using jquery . however it is not work . any idea what is wrong here .

```
     <textarea id="messageTxt" formControlName="message" rows="6" [placeholder]="'PLACEHOLDERS.MESSAGE' | translate" (keyup)="calculateMessagingSegmentCount(messageTxt.value)" #messageTxt></textarea>
```

from my component i am doing this

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'pc-sms-template-form',
      templateUrl: './sms-template-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sms-template-form.component.scss']
    })
    export class SmsTemplateFormComponent implements OnInit {
      ngOnInit() {

        $('#messageTxt').val("FEDEX@@@@@@ ");

       }
    }
```

I have imported `jquery` correctly and there is no compilation error however the textarea is not getting set with the value `FEDEX@@@@@@` . any idea what could be the reason behind this behavior. I know using `jquery` with typescript in an angular component is not great . but due to some certain requirement i have to use `jquery`.

thank

Comment: Use a `FormControl` there is no need for jquery in Angular 2+.

Comment: try, after change the value send a tigger $( "#messageTxt" ).trigger( "change" ); (but sure I don't know if work)

Answer (score 0):

The `OnInit` method is called before the view is rendered, use the `AfterViewInit` method instead:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pc-sms-template-form',
  templateUrl: './sms-template-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sms-template-form.component.scss']
})
export class SmsTemplateFormComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    $('#messageTxt').val("FEDEX@@@@@@ ");

   }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work either. implemented the  AfterViewInit interface and tried.

Comment: log the element in the console using ```console.log($('#messageTxt'); ``` and see what is the output

Comment: console.log($('#messageTxt').val()); 
 this prints undefined

Comment: can you show us the "sms-template-form.component.html" file

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something in keyup event, could you please check by removing keyup, that should fix your issue.

For your reference I have attached working snap.
[working sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVGmD.png)

Comment: hi sasi console.log($('#messageTxt').val()) this prints undefined

Comment: have you tried by removing (keyup)="calculateMessagingSegmentCount(messageTxt.value)"